# How to disable selection of range if date is disabled in mat-date-range-picker

Tags: angular, date, material-ui

Using mat-date-range-picker I want to disable selection of the date range, which has disabled dates in them.

In this (stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbeehp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html), since dates 5th Aug to 10th Aug are disabled, the selection of date range 4th Aug to 12th Aug should be invalid.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a way to force selecting valid range only at [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbeehp-hnj8a4?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.ts).

In this way, after selecting the start date you will disable the invalid date range.

**Algorithm:** (Considering your disabled range 5-10)

- If you select date less than 5 then the maximum selectable date should be date 4. E.g: If the first date is 1st January then the maximum selectable date will be 4th January.
- If you select date greater than 10 then the maximum selectable date should be next month's date 4. E.g: If the first date is 11th January then the maximum selectable date will be 4th February.

Hope, you'll understand the demo.